# How to change date format available for use with FullCalendar jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, date, fullcalendar

I'm using the ['FullCalendar' jQuery plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) however the format of my date string data is only in this format dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.

How can I parse this into the FullCalendar plugin so it is in one of the appropriate date formats that the plugin accepts?

I assume I need to utilise the [formatDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate) but I don't know how or where to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to get into a world of pain if you start playing around with date formats like that.

**Update**

Based on your comments, I would look at reformatting your input date (do this in javascript).  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) shows the many ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I am not using any language. The date output I have to work with is from the CMS I'm using and I have no control over it. I need to convert the given date format into one FullCalendar will accept. Is this going to be too difficult do you think? and should I find an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Even though I guess I could get some downvotes for this answer, here we go :-)

```
function myParseDate(indate){ //indate in your format eg. '15-September-2011 13:37:00'
    var datearraytmp1 = indate.split('-');
    var datearraytmp2 = datearraytmp1[2].split(' ');
    var datearraytmp3 = datearraytmp2[1].split(':');
        var datearray = [datearraytmp1[0], datearraytmp1[1], datearraytmp2[0], datearraytmp3[0], datearraytmp3[1], datearraytmp3[2]];
    var jsDate = new Date(datearray[2], monthStringToNumber(datearray[1]), datearray[0], datearray[3], datearray[4], datearray[5], 0);
}


var monthNames = {"January":0, "February":1, "March":2, "April":3, "May":4, "June":5, "July":6, "August":7, "September":8, "October":9, "November":10, "December":11};
function monthStringToNumber(monthname) {
    return monthNames[monthname];
}
```

This will give you the jsDate as a JavaScript date object which you can use with fullCalendar without too much problem. N.B that monthNames need to be changed into your language.

It's an ugly but working solution.

Edit: A cleaner solution would be to use http://www.datejs.com/ which seems to parse your input just fine :P

Comment: Just to make clear, @Christian Payne's solution is cleaner in most cases, but if you REALLY can't change the input this will at least get you a bit further with your coding :)